# Haskell Pattern Match Vectors

Tags: haskell, vector, pattern-matching

I'm following an online [tutorial on Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com). We define a function to add two-dimensional vectors, represented by tuple pairs of numbers. The following is the explicit type declaration, that ensures both inputs are two-dimensional vectors.

```
addVectors :: (Num a) => (a, a) -> (a, a) -> (a, a)
```

I understand why the following function definition uses pattern matching: it describes the patterns that input data should conform to.

```
addVectors (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
```

Why does the following alternative function definition not use pattern matching? (fst) and (snd) are guaranteed to work, because the inputs are explicitly declared to be tuples of length two.

What is the difference between the two function definitions?

```
addVectors a b = (fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b)
```

Comment: Well, it's just a different style of defining the same thing. What exactly is your question?

Comment: As a general advice, I'd recommend to learn to use pattern matching as much as possible, at least at the beginner level. The alternative with `fst,snd` is OK, but here on SO I've seen too many beginners to use dangerous functions like `head,tail,fromJust`, which often lead to crashes, when pattern matching is much safer, especially when warnings are turned on with `-Wall` (strongly recommended).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They differ in strictness. Suppose we rename them:

```
> let addVectorsStrict (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
> let addVectorsLazy a b = (fst a + fst b, snd a + snd b)
```

`addVectorsStrict undefined undefined` is `undefined`—the pattern matching is performed as soon as the outer `(,)` constructor of the result is demanded:

```
> case addVectorsStrict (error "A") (error "B") of (_, _) -> ()
*** Exception: A
```

But `addVectorsLazy undefined undefined` is `(undefined, undefined)`—the pattern matching is deferred until one of the *elements* of the result is demanded.

```
> case addVectorsLazy (error "A") (error "B") of (_, _) -> ()
()
```

Basically, `addVectorsLazy` always returns a tuple, where the elements may be unevaluated. `addVectorsStrict` may not return. You can also get the effect of `addVectorsLazy` using a lazy pattern match:

```
> let addVectorsAlsoLazy ~(x1, y1) ~(x2, y2) = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
> case addVectorsAlsoLazy (error "A") (error "B") of (_, _) -> ()
()
```

To get a better understanding of evaluation order, you can observe it using `Debug.Trace.trace`:

```
addVectors
  (trace "first tuple evaluated"
    (trace "x1 evaluated" 1, trace "y1 evaluated" 2))
  (trace "second tuple evaluated"
    (trace "x2 evaluated" 3, trace "y2 evaluated" 4))
```

The basic thing to remember about evaluation in Haskell is that it’s driven by pattern matching using `case` and function equations (which desugar to `case`).

It doesn’t matter much in this case, but you can write your functions lazily to avoid evaluating expensive computations if their results are never needed, or strictly to avoid the overhead of thunks if you know some result will *always* be needed.

In general, it’s a good idea to make the fields of your *data structures* strict unless you need them to be lazy, and make your *functions* lazy unless you need them to be strict. Here you could make a strict pair type to represent your vectors:

```
data Vector a = Vector !a !a
```

Comment: This is true, but probably much too subtle to be useful to OP or anyone who lands on this question from Google.

Comment: Thanks for understanding the question - I didn't phrase it well because I didn't know Haskell! Maybe I should follow the [official tutorial](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/patterns.html) instead.